# Node.js running under IIS6

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, iis-6

I'm looking to run node.js under IIS6 ( corporate environment, they are dead set on staying on IIS6 ). I've seen iisnode but it requires iis7.

My question is this: Is there an ISAPI redirect that can be used to connect IIS6 with node.js?

Comment: Might you be able to use Windows Azure to host your Node.js app instead? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

Comment: hmm.. maybe. I'll definitely give it a try!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We actually ended up doing the reverse and put IIS behind nodejs via [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

There are a number of benefits to doing this. For example IIS does not support web sockets, putting nodejs in front fixes this.

The only thing that you loose from node-iis is the process management, but there are plenty of alternative ways to get your node app running reliably as a service.

Comment: This may be what I need to use for now. Just need to do some juggling as the server has some https only, some https/http and others http using IIS connected to Active Directory. But that had nothing directly to do with my question however. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this process documented somewhere?

Comment: For recent projects we used [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows)